# Vulkan cannot find physical devices on linux

Tags: windows, ubuntu, graphics, driver, vulkan

I have been wanting to work with Vulkan, the new graphics API and have gotten it up and running with no problems on Windows 7. However I can't get Vulkan to work on linux. When I try running any of the LunarG samples, or even my own code, `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices` always says that there are no physical devices. Here is my setup:

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 (LTS) [x64]
GPU: Nvidia Geforce GT 730 2GB GDDR5
Driver: NVIDIA Binary driver - version 364.19 from nvidia-364 (open source)
Vulkan SDK: LunarG v1.0.17.0 [ latest version]
```

I was wondering if maybe there's a file for my GPU that I need to set an environment variable for, but I really don't know. As I said before, this worked on Windows 7 perfectly, but I can't seem to get this to work this the above configuration. I am able to create an instance with the LunarG standard validation layer and the correct extensions, but `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices` doesn't find any physical devices. It doesn't give an error, just says it can't find any physical devices. This has really got me stumped and I would really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: looks like the driver didn't install properly.

Comment: @ratchetfreak I used the "Additional Drivers" page to download and install my driver, I think that the driver installed properly, but maybe it did not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your distribution you may have to install the `nvidia-utils` package. See [this issue on my Vulkan repo for details](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/issues/184).

If this isn't the case for you check the directories Karl mentioned and check if there is no other ICD (maybe one from Intel) that may cause troubles. If you're on an optimus system with dual GPU you may need to explicitly activate the NVIDIA GPU.

The 730 should work fine on Linux, at least judging from the Linux hardware reports I got on my database like [this one](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=376).

Comment: I don't know what it was, maybe it was rebooting, but now Vulkan works for me now! My case was eerily similar to that xyproto guy's. After clicking through links on that page and doing what they say, the samples now work! And so does my code! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to set an environment variable if the driver installed properly.

One way to check for a proper installation is to look for the JSON file that identifies the driver.  For example, an nvidia driver will place a file called `nvidia_icd.json` in `/etc/vulkan/icd.d/`. `/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/` is another standard, but less common location.

It may also be the case that your GPU does not support Vulkan.  Be sure to check your GPU vendor's web pages to confirm support.  You may want to download the driver straight from the vendor's site in order to get one that they say has Vulkan support.

And are you sure that using the "Additional Drivers" page is supposed to give you a Vulkan driver?

You can refer to the loader documentation in the docs section at https://vulkan.lunarg.com for more info.

Comment: 1. Environment variables is for the SDK I believe 2. Yes I do have the `nvidia.json` file, but it's in `/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d`. Maybe the loader doesn't know to look there? 3. I know my GPU supports Vulkan because of [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver) website, and because it worked on Windows. 4. Supposedly, the driver I got supports Vulkan, and I don't get VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER. So I don't know, maybe number 2 is the problem